# What does "\b" mean in gdb string print output?

Tags: c, gdb

When I issue the command `p buf` on a buffer `buf` which contains nonprintable characters, I usually get octal output when gdb is trying to print a nonprintable character.

However, this time I got a string like this.

```
foobar\341\204\004\b\357\373\377\277
```

What does the `\b` mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\b` is the backspace character (`\010` if you're using ASCII).

Here are the rest of the escape sequences as defined by the C standard (5.2.2 Character display semantics):

> 2 Alphabetic escape sequences representing nongraphic characters in the execution
>   character set are intended to produce actions on display devices as follows:
>
> `\a` (alert) Produces an audible or visible alert without changing the active position.
>
> `\b` (backspace) Moves the active position to the previous position on the current line. If
>   the active position is at the initial position of a line, the behavior of the display
>   device is unspeciﬁed.
>
> `\f` (form feed) Moves the active position to the initial position at the start of the next
>   logical page.
>
> `\n` (new line) Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line.
>
> `\r` (carriage return) Moves the active position to the initial position of the current line.
>
> `\t` (horizontal tab) Moves the active position to the next horizontal tabulation position
>   on the current line. If the active position is at or past the last deﬁned horizontal
>   tabulation position, the behavior of the display device is unspeciﬁed.
>
> `\v` (vertical tab) Moves the active position to the initial position of the next vertical
>   tabulation position. If the active position is at or past the last deﬁned vertical
>   tabulation position, the behavior of the display device is unspeciﬁed.

Answer (score 2):

The `\b` denotes the backspace ASCII character (whose code is 8 or `\010` in octal)